# Sorting arrays of paired numbers and removing duplicates or overlaps?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, duplicates

How can I sort two arrays of coordinates in numerical order by the start coordinates e.g.

```
my @starts = (100,100,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends   = (150,125,250,350,450,550,550);
```

but choose the biggest difference if there are two matching in either the starts or ends list? E.g.

```
my @uniq_starts = (100,200,300,400,500);
my @unique_ends = (150,250,350,450,550);
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Also, how about if the lists are like this?

```
my @starts = (100,125,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends   = (150,175,250,350,450,550,550);
```

This would give me the following for the in between values:

```
-25, 25, 50, 50, 50, -25
```

I would need the following output:

```
my @uniq_starts = (100,200,300,400,500);
my @unique_ends = (175,250,350,450,550);
```

So my in between values are:

```
25, 50, 50, 50
```

I can get around this by just removing and ignoring any negative values, as I can imagine this would make things much more complicated.

Comment: Please post your coded attempt thus far.

Comment: Shouldn't the first item of `@unique_ends` be 150 rather than 125, or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "biggest difference"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, should be 150, I've edited the text!

Comment: Actually, to make it more complicated... the values may not necessarily match and there could be some overlap still. For example start = (100,125); ends = (150,200). Then I would require starts = (100); ends = (200) :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Set::IntSpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Set-IntSpan):

```
use Set::IntSpan;

my @starts = (100,100,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends   = (150,125,250,350,450,550,550);

my (@uniq_starts, @unique_ends);

for my $s (Set::IntSpan->new([map [$starts[$_], $ends[$_]], 0 .. $#starts])->spans) {
  push @uniq_starts, $s->[0];
  push @uniq_ends, $s->[1];
}

print join(",", @uniq_starts), "\n";
print join(",", @uniq_ends), "\n";
```

Or poor man's solution:

```
sub spans {
  my @s = sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0] or $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @_;
  my @res;
  while (@s > 1) {
    if ($s[0][1] >= $s[1][0]) {
      splice @s, 0, 2, [$s[0][0], $s[1][1]];
    } else {
      push @res, shift @s;
    }
  }
  push @res, @s;
  return @res;
}

my @starts = (100,100,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends   = (150,125,250,350,450,550,550);

my (@uniq_starts, @unique_ends);

for my $s (spans(map [$starts[$_], $ends[$_]], 0 .. $#starts)) {
  push @uniq_starts, $s->[0];
  push @uniq_ends, $s->[1];
}

print join(",", @uniq_starts), "\n";
print join(",", @uniq_ends), "\n";
```

You can check that it works flawless.

More functional `spans` version:

```
sub spans {
  return spans_(sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0] or $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @_);
}

sub spans_ {
  if (@_ > 1 and $_[0][1] >= $_[1][0]) {
    splice @_, 0, 2, [$_[0][0], $_[1][1]];
    goto &spans_;
  } elsif (@_) {
    return shift, spans_(@_);
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

P.S.: If somebody thinks that perl is concise language, compare same algorithm `spans` function in erlang. I don't even know how it would look in APL or J:

```
spans(L) -> spans_(lists:sort(L)).

spans_([{A, B}, {C, D}|T]) when B >= C ->
  spans_([{A, D}|T]);
spans_([H|T]) -> [H|spans_(T)];
spans_([]) -> [].
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Set::IntSpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Set-IntSpan/IntSpan.pm)?

```
use Set::IntSpan;

my @starts = (100,100,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends = (150,125,250,350,450,550,550);
my @spec = map { "$starts[$_]-$ends[$_]" } 0..$#starts;
my $p = Set::IntSpan->new(@spec);
print "$p\n";
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there is a matching pair in the second list, from what I can tell?

Comment: E.g. (104643,104837)
(104891,104950)
(104912,105195)
(104964,105195)
(106635,107245)
(112029,112166)
(113174,113177)
(114546,114688)
(114773,114940)
(115057,115165)

Comment: Prints both out for the ones ending 105195!

Comment: @Steve: right. Missed part of the spec. Updating my answer completely.

Comment: Thanks runrig! Set::IntSpan sounds interesting. Will have a read :)

Comment: +1 Good idea to use Set::IntSpan. You could create `@spec` a bit more easily with `map()`, along these lines: `my @spec = map "$starts[$_]-$ends[$_]", 0 .. $#starts`.

Answer (score 0):

Use some list transformations:

```
my @starts = (100,100,200,300,400,500,525);
my @ends   = (150,125,250,350,450,550,550);

my (%starts_seen, %ends_seen);
my @ar = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }   # result in ascending sort order of @starts
         grep ! $starts_seen{$_->[0]}++,
         sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] }   # descending sort b -> a
         grep ! $ends_seen{$_->[1]}++,
         sort { $b->[1] <=> $b->[1] }   # descending sort b -> a
         map  [ $starts[$_],$ends[$_] ],
         0 .. $#starts;

print "($_->[0],$_->[1]) " for @ar;
```

this results in:

```
(100,150) (200,250) (300,350) (400,450) (500,550)
```

Regards

rbo

Edit: modified code to reflect sort order of sorts

Comment: How about if I wanted to get 100,150 as the first pair, so the pairs are always the largest ones?

Comment: Steve, you use in sort: {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} for ascending and $b->[0] <=> $a->[0]} for descending sort (I'll add a remark)

Comment: It is slow and overcomplicated. Why you sort it three times? Compare poor man's solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449983/sorting-arrays-of-paired-numbers-and-removing-duplicates-or-overlaps/3451206#3451206

Comment: What if you had starts (500, 550) and ends (525, 560)...do we want to end up with just (500, 560)? This does not do that.

Comment: runrig, right, this will **not** correctly handle int spans. This was not originally stated in the question - I read that  (the span request) later in an additional post of the o.p. -